# How to select a folder containing the latest modified file?

Tags: c#

I am stuck with this code trying to fetch a specific RemoteID information from a file within a directory that contains many similar but older files under different sub-directories. I can't seem to be able to extract this parameter from the ***latest*** modified file.

My code so far looks through the whole "N:\WBS Data\DL Archive\DL Data Files\" for the latest .ini file in all sub-directories, does the trick and quits!

I need it to repeat the same for one directory deeper in the hierarchy; i.e. "N:\WBS Data\DL Archive\DL Data Files\x folder", "N:\WBS Data\DL Archive\DL Data Files\y folder", "N:\WBS Data\DL Archive\DL Data Files\z folder", and so forth.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Refresh_WGL_Configs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string tempFile = "";
            string tempCurrFile = "";
            string remoteID = "";
            string groupID = "";


            try
            {

                foreach ( string d in Directory.GetFiles(@"N:\WBS Data\DL Archive\DL Data Files", "*.ini", SearchOption.AllDirectories).OrderByDescending(f => File.GetCreationTime(f)).Take(1))

                {
                    string currDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(d);

                    // Set ini file and temporary text filenames
                        tempFile = currDir + @"\XferStat.txt";
                        tempCurrFile = currDir + @"\XferStat.ini";

                    // Convert the ini file to a text file then extract remote ID
                    convert_to_text(tempCurrFile, tempFile);
                    remoteID = grab_remote_ID(tempFile);

                    // Clean up temporary text file
                    File.Delete(tempFile);

                    // Extract group ID
                    groupID = grab_group_ID(currDir);

                    // Copy files from C drive to D drive
                    _C_to_D(remoteID, groupID);

                    // Reset ID's
                    groupID = "";
                    remoteID = "";

                }

            }

            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            }

        }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't `SearchOption.AllDirectories` give you that behavior by default, if you give it the outer path (i.e. without the list of subfolders)?

Comment: Or, is what you want to do to group the latest `.ini` files by what subfolder they are in?